# Bot ping is coming nan

Tags: discord.js, bots, ping

I was trying code for ping and I end up like this.. new to coding any help will greatly be appreciated...

Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping' ,
    description: "this is a ping command.",
    execute(message, arguments, client) {
        message.reply('Calculating ping...').then((resultmessage) => {
            const ping = resultmessage.createdtimestamp - message.createdtimestamp

            resultmessage.edit(`Bot latency: ${ping}`)

        })
    }
}
```

am using command handler .. main code is.

```js
if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args,client);
```

and here whats the output and its bad...
**Bot latency: NaN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because properties, in this case, `createdtimestamp`, are case sensitive. So you need to replace `createdtimestamp` with [`createdTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createdTimestamp).

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping' ,
    description: "this is a ping command.",
    execute(message,arguments,client){
        message.reply('Calculating ping...').then((resultmessage) => {
            const ping = resultmessage.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp

            resultmessage.edit(`Bot latency: ${ping}`)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you but why is it so high? like 590?

Comment: That's how long it's taking to get your message and send another message in response to it. That is not the API ping, for that refer to https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/WebSocketManager?scrollTo=ping . Also, welcome to SO, when an answer solves your question accept it using the tickmark on the left side to let others know what worked.